# NDVI raster to polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, ndvi, pixel

I have an NDVI raster created through a Parrot sequoia and Pix4D. When imported into QGIS 3.0.2 it is shown as a singleband gray render type with a range of -0.355826 to 0.905562.[image: NDVI Raster]

I want to create polygons according to the raster values of similar pixel ranges. I have tried the GDAL polygonize (raster to vector) tool, but only get values of 1 or 0. I then found a solution that required me to convert the raster from FLOAT to INT. Which I did, but again only got values of 1 or 0 when I used the GDAL polygonize tool.

I'm I missing something? Totally new to processing NDVI data.

Comment: Before converting your raster to integer values scale up yout raster using raster calculator. E.g. the expression: "your_raster@1" * 10. Converting this to integer you will get values from -3 to 9.

Comment: This worked a treat!